# Two issues with jCrop fancy box in FireFox and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox, jcrop

Having a bit of a fight with JCrop and FancyBox in cross browser support, this is what i am doing. The application is a simple cropping functionality, the user selects an image using file for razor and jCrop is initilised into a fancy box, the user is presented with a nice dotted box in the default aspect in the top left corner.

This works across IE, Chrome, FF (80% of the time) and Safari (70%) of the time.

The code is below to initialise the box and couple of screen shots on what happens most of the time.

Issue 1: Selection Box is closed into the top left corner (Only happens 4/10 times)

[Issue 1](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t1.0-9/10257254_10152563905410851_5859945421389373825_n.jpg)

Issue 2: FancyBox opens in a very small window (Happens a lot in FF and Safari not in IE Chrome)

[Issue 2](https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t1.0-9/10418305_10152563905420851_9165817253055030093_n.jpg)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jcrop_api;

    function showCoordsBanner(c) {
        $('#ProfileBanner_ImageCrop_XCoord').val(c.x);
        $('#ProfileBanner_ImageCrop_YCoord').val(c.y);
        $('#ProfileBanner_ImageCrop_Width').val(c.w);
        $('#ProfileBanner_ImageCrop_Height').val(c.h);
    };

    function showCoordsProfile(c) {
        $('#Image_ImageCrop_XCoord').val(c.x);
        $('#Image_ImageCrop_YCoord').val(c.y);
        $('#Image_ImageCrop_Width').val(c.w);
        $('#Image_ImageCrop_Height').val(c.h);
    };

    function bindPreview(e, coordFunction, aspectRatio, setSelector) {
        $.fancybox({
            href: "#cropfancybox",
            scrolling: 'none',
            autoSize: false, //Fix for FireFox Load
            autoDimensions: false,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            afterShow: function () {
                $('.fancybox-outer').append(
                $('<div>Drag the corners of the above box to crop your photo</div>', {
                    'style': 'display:inline-block; width:100%; padding:10px 0 0 0; margin-top: 5px'
                }).append(
                $('<input/>', {
                    'class': 'button',
                    'type': 'button',
                    'value': 'Finished Cropping',
                    'onClick': '$.fancybox.close();',
                    'style': 'float:right;'
                })));
                jcrop_api.setSelect(setSelector);
            }
        });

        $('#preview').Jcrop({
            onChange: coordFunction,
            onSelect: coordFunction,
            boxWidth: 1000,
            aspectRatio: aspectRatio
        }, function () {
            jcrop_api = this;
        });
        jcrop_api.setImage(e.target.result);
    }

    $('#File').change(function (evt) {
        if (window.FileReader) {
            var f = evt.target.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                bindPreview(e, showCoordsBanner, 3 / 1, [0, 0, 200, 200]);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    });

    $('#profileImage').change(function (evt) {
        if (window.FileReader) {
            var f = evt.target.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = reader.onload = function (e) {
                bindPreview(e, showCoordsProfile, 1 / 1, [0, 0, 200, 200]);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide a working jsfiddle sample